# When $D$ and $D[x]$ have isomorphic $t$-class groups

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ideals

In a [1987 paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927878708823540), Stefania Gabelli studies the map 
$$\psi: \{ \text{ideals of $D$} \} \rightarrow\{\text{ideals of $D[x]$\}}$$
$$\psi(I) = ID[x]$$

for a domain $D$. In fact $\psi$ always induces an injective homomorphism of $t$-class groups and Gabelli shows that

> $\psi$ is an isomorphism if and only if $D$ is integrally closed.

An immediate corollary is that if $D[x]$ has trivial $t$-class group, then $D$ must be integrally closed, useful when investigating properties of $D[x]$ inherited from $D$.

My question is the following:

> Suppose $D$ and $D[x]$ have $t$-class groups which are isomorphic but *not* by the natural isomorphism $\psi$. What can we say about $D$?

It would be great if $D$ would still be integrally closed, but I strongly suspect this is not the case.  Is there a nice counterexample to put this to rest?
As Gabelli remarks, if $D[x]$ has trivial $t$-class group one can prove directly that $D$ is integrally closed, so furnishing a counterexample would require at least looking at nontrivial $t$-class groups.

**Note** For those not familiar with $*$-operations but curious nonetheless.... you might look at sections $32,34$ of Gilmer's Multiplicative Ideal Theory or at Zafrullah's *[Putting t-invertibility to use](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268549570_Putting_T-Invertibility_to_Use)* for a fast-paced overview.